# Proof of asymptotic relation

Tags: asymptotics

$$\int ^\pi _0 \frac{\sin(\frac{d k}{2}\cos{\psi})}{\frac{d k}{2}\cos{\psi}}\sin(\psi)e^{-ik\rho\sin(\psi-\alpha)} \, d\psi \sim  C \frac{\sin(\frac{d k}{2}\alpha)}{\frac{d k}{2}\alpha}$$

Where $C$ is a complex constant. The relation is valid for $dk\gg1$ and $k\rho\gg1$ and $\alpha \ll 1$

Can anyone give any ideas as to how such a relation would be shown?

Numerical LHS:
[image]
Absolute value of LHS:
[image]
Absolute value of RHS:
[image]

Comment: I changed $dk>>1$ to $dk\gg 1$.  That is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation

Comment: @Chappers So clever. e^{-i k \rho \sin(\psi-\alpha)} becomes $\delta(\psi-(\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha))$

Comment: Don't forget the width factor that comes from the second derivative at the stationary point.

Comment: Width factor? Do you mean the complex constant?

Comment: @grdgfgr do your calculations properly. It is not just a delta function, you have to follow the calculations in the linked article carefully!

Comment: Btw: i would guess the result changes depending on $dk>>\rho k$ or $dk<<\rho k$